# How to create label on bevel line in Inno Setup

Tags: label, inno-setup

Yesterday I found a new setup. It has a label on a bevel line. So, how to create and setting label on bevel line like this in Inno Setup?

[image: Like this Picture]

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a [group box control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-group-boxes) (known as the [`TGroupBox`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TGroupBox) in Delphi/VCL), not the bevel.

But the group box control is not exposed in Inno Setup.

As an alternative, just place a `TLabel` on top of the `TBevel`. Make sure you set label's `Transparent` property to `False`.

On Windows Vista and newer, you can also add a [hair space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200a/index.htm) around for a padding. You need Unicode version of Inno Setup for that (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  Bevel: TBevel;
  Caption: TLabel;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, '', '');

  Bevel := TBevel.Create(WizardForm);
  with Bevel do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Shape := bsFrame;
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(8);
    Width := ScaleX(417);
    Height := ScaleY(220);
  end;

  Caption := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with Caption do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := Bevel.Left + ScaleX(8);
    Top := Bevel.Top - ScaleY(6);
    Transparent := False;
    Caption := 'Caption';

    { On Vista and newer, add padding using a hair space }
    if GetWindowsVersion >= $06000000 then
      Caption := #$200A + Caption + #$200A;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very mush Martin Prikryl

Comment: The 3D bevel is a Windows 9x relic these days.